# Topology, Calculate the set lock $A= \{(p, p^{2}): p \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subset I^{2}_{0}$

Tags: general-topology

Calculate the set lock $A= \{(p, p^{2}): p \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subset I^{2}_{0}$
where $I^{2}_{0}$
Is the square ordered unit provided with the lexicographic order.

Comment: What is a "set lock"?

Comment: es la cerradura